# What does X-COM stand for?

Tags: xcom-series

Is the name of the X-COM organization some acronym, a shortcut? Is it explained anywhere?

Comment: The answer is in the second paragraph of the [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-com#X-COM_games) on X-Com.

Comment: I just created an x-com-series tag to be used in cases like this, as it's not specific to any single game.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

X-COM stands for "Extraterrestrial Combat Force", an organization in the game.